# Is it possible to use RegEx to find a string of its superset in mongodb and node.js?

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

I am using node.js and Mongoose, and I am wondering about how to find a word by its superset word with RegEx.

for example, is it possible to find the string `example` by its superset string `examplee` or `foo` with the string `foox`?

I was tried to google it and read the documentation of MongoDB but haven't found any solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is search use case.

You could find the subset using superset by phrase search with a slop parameter.

[Refer](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/phrase/)

or

you can use fuzzy search.

But these will bring not only subset but also some other terms.

For eg, when you search for `foods` you may expect `foo` to return but not `fee`. It may bring `fee` but with lowest ranking. You can filter out at front-end.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution I was looking for! Since in my case, I use a short query for every request, therefore, I split the query string to get an array of subsets and then use the solutions you mentioned above. Really appreciate your advice!